# Achieving the same performance that Node.JS provides in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js

This is what we see on the Node.JS website

> Node.js® is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily
>   building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an
>   event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and
>   efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run
>   across distributed devices.

Is it possible to develop non-blocking applications with ASP.NET MVC and get the same performance (handle the same number of requests per second and process them)?

Using [async/await](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) in the **ASP.NET MVC controllers** help to get the same performance (handle the same number of requests per second and process them) that a **Node.JS** application also provide?

Comment: [Performance Rant](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to develop non-blocking applications with ASP.NET MVC and get the same performance (handle the same number of requests per second and process them)?

Technically, this question is invalid, since there will probably be some load patterns / server configurations / state management setups that Node.js will be faster at, and some that ASP.NET will be faster at.

From an architecture perspective, yes, `async`/`await` gives you a similar approach to handling requests as Node.js, with one important difference. Node.js is strictly single-threaded (only using its thread pool for offloading work that *would* be done asynchronously if an asynchronous API existed for it). So, it will only execute application code for a single request at a time. ASP.NET follows a more complex model: it can be both parallel *and* asynchronous simultaneously.

In other words, Node.js uses single-threaded asynchrony, while ASP.NET uses multi-threaded asynchrony.

So, I'd expect Node.js and ASP.NET to both perform similarly on a single-core processor, with ASP.NET doing better on a multi-core (a common Node.js approach to multi-core is to run multiple instances of Node with a load balancer in front, but then caching and server state gets slower). Of course, there's only one way to test how they'll both perform *for your application:* write a reasonable test case and run it.